# Remove matching values from two columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have the following data set generated from the equation

`df.loc[:,51] = [1217.0, -20.0, 13970.0, -74]`

I dropped the negative values (specific values) and got this

`df.loc[:,52] = [1217.0, 0, 13970.0, 0]`

Now I am trying to get another column with the dropped values

`df.loc[:,53] = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[df.loc[:,51], df.loc[:,52]])`

I want this result.
The values that are dropped

`df.loc[:,53] = [0,-20, 0,-74]`

But I got the following error

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When asking a question, please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - in this case, at the very least provide all your code used to drop negative values. If you can, try to create a dataset using code that we could work with too. Check out the [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) docs - it doesn't do what you're trying to do and the `subset` arg accepts column names, not a list of Series objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df.loc[:,53] = np.where(df.loc[:,51] == df.loc[:,52], 0, df.loc[:,51])
```

Here, I've done it with a sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
     'rating': [4, -4, 3.5, -15, 5]
 })
df.loc[(df['rating'] < 0 ), 'new_col'] = 0
df.loc[(df['rating'] > 0 ), 'new_col'] = df['rating']
df['dropped'] = np.where(df['rating'] == df['new_col'], 0, df['rating'])
df
```